# ajax call success issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

In this case status will always be successful:

```
$.post($('#form_url').val(), { email: email_val },function(data, status){
    console.log(status, data);
    if(status === "success"){
        step_1.fadeOut(function(){
            step_2.fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

The console.log data it returns the following:

```
{"status":false,"error":"You already participate in the competition"}
```

How can I access status of false?

I need to do something like this:

```
if (status === 'error'){//do sth}
```

Comment: Did you try `data.status`?

Comment: `data.status`...? Also, it's a boolean value, not a string so comparing it to `success` would not work.

Comment: so: `if(data.status)` ???

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `dataType` as `json` as your response is a json string, then the `data` will be a object. Then you can access the `status` and `error` properties using [Member Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

```
$.post($('#form_url').val(), {
    email: email_val
}, function (data, status) {
    if (data.status) {
        step_1.fadeOut(function () {
            step_2.fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        console.log(data.error)
    }
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

use the modern ajax call syntax:

```
$.ajax({
      url:     $('#form_url').val()
    , data:    { email: email_val }
    , method:  "POST"
}).always(function(data_or_jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_or_errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, data_or_jqXHR);
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    step_1.fadeOut(function(){
        step_2.fadeIn();
    });
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   // do sth on error
});
```

for detailed explanation of the method consult the [jquery api docs on `ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).